# Linux has No C Man Pages

Tags: c, linux, manpage

This is peculiar. I recently installed an operating system called "Semplice" Linux. It's debian based and very similar to Crunchbang (Lightweight and openbox-oriented).

That aside, I cannot run `man printf` or any C command for that matter.

I can, however, run `man echo` and `man cat` and other linux commands, but no C commands.

I have already run: `mandb` to no avail.

**Note:** I did not have to manually install C (build-essential or libc6 or anything).

Comment: Is this more appropriate for Server Fault?

Comment: tried `man 3 <function name>` ???

Comment: for printf() try man "3p printf" if it is you have gcc package installed only it will have the man pages of C

Comment: ...either ServerFault or SuperUser, yes. It's a system administration problem, not a programming question.

Comment: Similar question: http://superuser.com/questions/393772/man-pages-in-linux

Comment: @Jeyaram I wrote a loop to iterate 1-9 to no avail. It has been fixed (answer chose)

Comment: Install `manpages-dev` package (or its equivalent on your distribution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'manpages-dev' package should contain the man pages for C. I have not used semplice, but that is the package name on other debian based systems.

Comment: What would I do without you?